# How to set URL on JSP when it depends on user locale, Spring MVC or Hybris

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, sap-commerce-cloud

I have some page controller with several values in @RequestMapping, for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"foo", "bar"})
public class FooBarController {...}
```

And in some JSP I need set URL to this page controller, but this URL should depend on user locale, for example: if a user selects EN locale of a site that URL should be "/foo" or if the user selects FR locale URL should be "bar".

And the question, how it's possible to do using Spring (or Hybris) because I think that if-else with a condition like:

```
<c:when test="${locale == 'EN'}">...</c:when>
```

on JPS is not such a good solution?

Comment: how is locale being tracked? is it a user property, something in the session? if the first then you should be able to get contextual user form spring. if the latter, you can get session from HttpServletRequest. you can then set that url based on your findings in the model and just use that value.

Comment: @mavriksc yes, locale is user property, which is stored in DB and also contained in session.

Comment: Store it in a hiddenfield or session

Comment: so have `<a href="${localeBasedURL}">` in your jsp and in your controller have `locale.language== "FR" ? model.put("localeBasedURL","http://siteurl/foo") : 
model.put("localeBasedURL","http://siteurl/bar")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your link is created. 
1. You can add the link the localized .properties files. For example:

```
*fr.properties -  myLink=/foo 
*en.properties - myLink/bar
```

and use it in the JSP/TAG.

2. You can create a custom CMSLinkComponent on which you localize the url property  and use the cms component as a link.
3. You can setup a global property in the AbstractPageController and add it to model. Something like localePrefix=currentLocale(). After that rename your mappings like this `/fr/foo ; en/foo and use this prefix before the links. ${localePrefix}/foo`